# JSON Post Request is not working in ASP.NET5 MVC but is working in ASP.NET4.5 MVC

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an example which sends a JSON post request to MVC controller. This example works in ASP.NET 4.5 but won’t work in the newest ASP.NET 5 release. Do I miss anything in this example?

1. I created a model, but I didn’t bind it to database. It will be just the object created in the memory.

   ```
   public class SalesOrder
   {
       public int SalesOrderId { get; set; }
       public string CustomerName { get; set; }
       public string PONumber { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. I use Visual Studio 2015 to create that model based controller and its associated CRUD views. However, in this example, I will only run the “Create” view.
3. Inside the controller, I hard coded a SalesOrder object list and it only contains an item. I will use it to work with the CRUD views.

   ```
   private List<SalesOrder> salesOrderList = 
       new List<SalesOrder> ( 
           new SalesOrder[] 
           { 
               new SalesOrder() 
                   { 
                        SalesOrderId = 1, 
                        CustomerName = "David", 
                        PONumber = "123" 
                   } 
           });
   ```
4. Inside the controller, I also create a new function to process the “Save” request. The request will just change the CustomerName property of the model then bounce back with the JSON result.

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public JsonResult Save(SalesOrder salesOrderViewModel)
   {
       salesOrderViewModel.CustomerName = "David returns";

       return Json(new { salesOrderViewModel });
   }
   ```
5. In the Create.cshtml, I created a button and attach JQuery script to its click event.

   ```
   <p><button id="saveButton">Save</button></p>
   ```

This is the JQueryScript.

```
    $(function () {
        var clickFunc = function () {

            var salesOrderViewModel = {
                    "salesOrderViewModel": {
                    "SalesOrderId": 123,
                    "CustomerName": "ab",
                    "PONumber": "2",
                    }
            }

            $.ajax({
                    url: "/SalesOrders/Save/",
                    type: "POST",
                    cache: false,
                    data: JSON.stringify(salesOrderViewModel),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                });
            }

        $('#saveButton').click(clickFunc)
    })
```

6. I click the "Save" button in Create.cshtml to trigger the post request.
7. I set the debug break point in the controller and verify the coming post request. In ASP.NET 4.5, the JSON deserialization is working, and it shows all the values.

However, in ASP.NET 5, an empty object is returned.

In ASP.NET 5 case, if press F12 to start the debugger in Microsoft Edge, then it shows the Post request does have the correct values, but for some reasons, they are not passed to MVC controller.

Please see these screen shots:
http://i63.tinypic.com/68vwnb.jpg

Do I miss anything? 
Thanks for helping…

Comment: The data should be just `data: { SalesOrderId: 123, CustomerName: "ab", PONumber: "2" },` and remove the `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` option.

Comment: I tried it again without the contentType but still not working. Thanks

Comment: Works for me. There is clearly something else in you code that you have not shown us that causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to specify the name of the parameter. Try:

```
           var salesOrderViewModel = {
                    "SalesOrderId": 123,
                    "CustomerName": "ab",
                    "PONumber": "2",
            }
```

Comment: It still won't work after remove the parameter name.

Comment: Try removing the `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`

Comment: @DCruz22, If you remove the `contentType`, then it needs to be just `data: salesOrderViewModel,` (not stringified)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to especify fromBody in the Controller.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Save([FromBody]SalesOrder salesOrderViewModel)
{
    salesOrderViewModel.CustomerName = "David returns";

    return Json(new { salesOrderViewModel });
}
```

Comment: The question relates to asp.net-mvc, not asp.net-web-api

Comment: The `[FromBody]` is not necessary when using the model binder and custom model.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for DCruz22 and Stephen Muecke. 
The working version of the script is:

```
$(function () {

    var clickFunc = function () {

        var salesOrderViewModel = {
            "salesOrderViewModel": {
                "SalesOrderId": 0,
                "CustomerName": "ab",
                "PONumber": "2",
                "MessageToClient": "POST to server"
            }
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: "/SalesOrders/Save/",
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            data: salesOrderViewModel
        });
    }

    $('#saveButton').click(clickFunc)
})
```

I found the parameter name "salesOrderViewModel" is not a problem. With it, the script is still working.

Actually, this question is a simplified version of my original problem. My originally problem is starting from the knockoutJs. Below is the script doing the data binding. After user clicks the "Save" button, the self.save function() is called and the script will send the post request including the data model to the MVC controller.

```
SalesOrderViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);

    self.save = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/SalesOrders/Save/",
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,

            data: ko.toJSON(self),

            success: function (data) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

The problem is "ko.toJSON(self)" includes some other information. Below is the request body I captured from the Microsoft Edge debugger.

```
{"SalesOrderId":0, 
 "CustomerName":"chiang123", 
 "PONumber":"123", 
 "MessageToClient":null, 
 "__ko_mapping__":{
       "ignore":[],
       "include":["_destroy"],
       "copy":[],
       "mappedProperties":{
             "SalesOrderId":true,
             "CustomerName":true,
             "PONumber":true,
             "MessageToClient":true}}}
```

You can see all data starts from "**ko_mapping**" is KnockoutJs specific. Do I need to manually trim those data in order to make this work? Per information, obviously the same implementation should work in ASP.NET 4.5 but I just haven't try it yet. Many thanks...